# Selenium - PageObjectFactory - referencing element on the same page after it reloads

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am testing a web page using Webdriver and Java.

The test page contains List of Records and i click on the "Employee ID" title hyperlink and the records should be sorted in the ascending order of the employee IDs and there should be a small icon beside the "Employee ID" column indicating that the results are now sorted.

Here is the code i have:

```
public Class ResultsPage extends SlowLoadableComponent<ResultsPage> {

    @FindAll({ @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "some xpath"), @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "another xpath") })
    public List<WebElement> resultsTableElement;

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@title='A system assigned identifier for the Employee record.']")
    public WebElement employeeIDColumnTitle;

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@title='A system assigned identifier for the Employee record.']/following-sibling::img")
    public WebElement ascOrDescIcon;

    public ResultsPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(new SystemClock(),20);
        this.driver = driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Start.TIME_OUT);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void load() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        LOGGER.info("From the load method");
    }

    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {
        boolean loaded = false;
        if (resultsTableElement.size() > 0) {
            loaded = true;
        }
        LOGGER.warn("isloaded method failed ");
        Assert.assertTrue(loaded, "Looks like the Claim Results Search Frame is not loaded yet");
    }

    public void testThis() {
        //some code here
        systemIDColumnTitle.click();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); //Calling the initElements of the same page again to see that the element 
        LOGGER.info(ascOrDescIcon.getAttribute("src")); //This line always fails saying that the element is not found.
    }

}
```

Comment: What you want to do exactly?

Comment: I have a page and when i click on the sort results link, the page refreshes and creates a new element on the same page..so how do i get access to this new element? ..Please let me know if the question is still not clear?

Answer (score 1):

From the comment you have specified, why can't you have locator defined in the same page object like:

```
@FindBy(id="newElement")
private WebElement newElement
```

This `newElement` points to the new element that got created after certain operation.

#### Edit:

As per your comment, you can directly call the get methods rather than instantiating another time. Kindly understand, that all `@FindBy` `WebElements` are proxys; Only when you call methods on it, they will be fetched (using the locator you have given) and does the specific operation.

So thats the reason, you can have the elements on your pageobject and calling `initElements` wont throw error, even the `@FindBy` aren't found!

Comment: but when the page is created this element does not exist on the page and it is created only when i click on a specific link..I am calling `PageFactory.InitElements` after clicking on the link so that the new element is initialized and points to the webelement.. My question is should i call `PageFactory.initElements` or `this.get()`